# Como atualizar estador do Value do DropDownButton no Flutter com GetX sem utilizar o SetState?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou tentando fazer um DropDownButton no meu projeto através de um FutureBuilder. Antes de utilizar o GetX para atualizar o estado do Value, eu utilizava o setState e funcionava. Após modificar o projeto para a utilização do GetX como gerenciador de estado não consegui atualizar e fica dando erro. Seguem os códigos:

```
                          DropdownButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          ),
                          iconSize: 20,
                          hint: Text("Cidade"),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "WorkSansSemiBold",
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          items: _listCidades?.map((item){
                            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(item.nome),
                              value: item.id,
                            );
                          })?.toList() ?? [],
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              mySelection = value;
                            });
                          },
                          value: mySelection,
                        ),
```

Código com GetX para gerenciar o estado:

```
                            FutureBuilder<List<Cidade>>(
                          future: _loginController.getCity(),
                          builder: (context,  snapshot) {
                            return DropdownButton(
                              hint: Text("Cidade"),
                                items: snapshot.data?.map((cidade) =>
                                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      child: Text(cidade.nome),
                                      value: cidade.id,
                                    )
                                )?.toList() ?? [],
                              onChanged: (newValue){
                                _loginController.setCidade(RxString(newValue));
                                mySelection = newValue;
                              },
                              value: GetX<LoginController>(
                                builder: (_)=> _.cidade,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        )
```

Código do controller:

```
  var _selectCidade = "0".obs;
  get cidade => this._selectCidade.value;
  set cidade(value) => this._selectCidade.value = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instanciar o controller dentro da classe e depois usa-lo para acessar a variável cidade que está sendo observada.

Para refletir as alterações, a variavel.obs deve estar dentro de um Obx, conforme código abaixo, assim cada vez que ela for alterada, o widget será reconstruído

Existem maneira de não precisar instanciar o controller como por exemplo o uso de GetView, GetBuilder, etc...

```
final MeuController controller = MeuController();
    
Obx(() => DropdownButton(
              hint: Text("Cidade"),
              items: snapshot.data
                      ?.map((cidade) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            child: Text(cidade.nome),
                            value: cidade.id,
                          ))
                      ?.toList() ??
                  [],
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                _loginController.setCidade(RxString(newValue));
                mySelection = newValue;
              },
              value: controller .cidade,
            ));
```